# TextField right alignment issue javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have textfield that containing a value and that value should be Right alignment.

When i run the application it display the text left alignment but i set the Right alignment.
and problem with 3rd textfield.

After clicking the update button it works fine.

So may i know why it is behave different.

Code:

```
    import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldAlignment extends Application {

    TextField rText;

    File file;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        rText = new TextField("updated right1 updated right2 updated right3 updated right4");
        rText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        Button btn = new Button("update");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                rText.setText("updated right1 updated right2 updated right3 updated right4");

//              applyWorkaround();
            }
        });     

        final Label labelFile = new Label();

          Button btn2 = new Button();
          btn2.setText("Open FileChooser'");
          btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                  FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

                  //Set extension filter
                  FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("AVI files (*.exml)", "*.exml");
                  fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

                  //Show open file dialog
                  file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

//                rText.setText(file.getPath());
              }
          });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(rText, btn, btn2);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what it's doing that you don't expect? When I run this there is more text than can be displayed in the text field anyway; so the text field is "full" and there is no additional space for alignment. If I change the size of the window immediately on running the application, the text is right aligned. Similarly, if you change the code so the text field is initialized to a short string, it appears right aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i run the application, first time it display the text from left alignment but i called the setAlignment(Pos.Center_Right) and expected result is textfield display the text (Right Alignment) but when clicking on the update button it work fine and it display the text in the textfield from right side. ? So my question if i set Right alignment then it should display on the Right in first attempt. Why it display the text on the right alingment on clicking the button.?

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting what "alignment" means. Alignment tells the text field how to position the text when there is more space in the text field than the text occupies. In your example, there is no extra space, so the alignment doesn't do anything. Change the initial text to just "x" and you should see the alignment take effect. (On my system, nothing changes when I press "Update". Not sure what you mean there.)

Answer (score -1):

Put the setalignment and settext after you add the TextField to the Scene.

Ref: Java API docs for Node

> Node objects may be constructed and modified on any thread as long
>   they are not yet attached to a Scene. An application must attach nodes
>   to a Scene, and modify nodes that are already attached to a Scene, on
>   the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: But if i created the UI using scene builder then how to perform this functionality.

Comment: Problem is how to modify to Scene object for adding the setAlignment and setText method functionality if created the UI using the scene builder (Scene builder provide the Alignment property but it does not work for me.